# Can you create kubernetes cluster with raspberry pi and a notebook

Tags: cluster

I am new to containers, docker and kubernetes but I see many videos where people create raspberry pi clusters and run servers (e.g. minecraft) on them. I would like to know if it is possible to create a cluster with for example a raspberry pi and a notebook, and if this is possible to maybe add other devices in the future. The goal would be to share the workload of the main device (notebook) with other devices in the cluster. Is it possible to run a game and get for example more FPS using this setup rather than just the notebook?

Comment: See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133693/5538  In short, the answer to *"Is it possible to run a game and get for example more FPS using this setup rather than just the notebook?"* is **no**.

Comment: Thank you for the short answer :)

Comment: Worth considering what you plan on using on the cluster. For example do the packages provide Arm compatible docker containers (or Kubernetes packages), are those packages 64 bit only (if so make sure you install the 64 bit Raspbian OS or whatever OS you are using). I would also recommend using K3s instead as this will require less resources to run.